# i want to make an icon before a text in header html

Tags: html, css, header, icons

I want to make this icon before this text

[image]

I got this code in HTML

```
<div class="header" > <img src="cir.png" style="height:30px;"/>  email things</div>
```

and this in styyle css

```
.header {
  background-color: gray;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left:100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3;
}
```

Comment: Please show us a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem, and give a fuller description of exactly the problem you are facing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by simply removing the grid configurations of your `<style>`, effectively having:

```html
    <style>
        .header {
          background-color: gray;
          padding-left: 100px;
          color: white;
          font-size: 3;
        }
    </style>
```

Here's a snippet you can play with:
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-framework-e5g9ci?file=/index.html:106-287

Answer (score 0):

Use `<i>` in the HTML for icons, you can mess around with its page placement in the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it grid, but if you use "display: flex;" you can get the result that you want.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<style>
    .header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: gray;
        padding-left: 100px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 3;
    }

    .header img {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <img src="/icon.png" style="height:30px;" />
        <p>email things</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```